# Random Generator within range

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, random, getch

Hi i know that there  is already a question for the random generator within range, but I don't understand it. I am a beginner in C, and I only know java. In this program I am trying to create a math tutor in C. The program will randomly generate two numbers from 1 to 10, and an operator. It runs, but it does not show the next line, and it keeps showing incorrect answer. Also, why does VS2010 is saying that getch() is undefined? Here is the code:

```
 int ans;
 int ans1;
 int num1 = rand() % 10 + 2;
 int num2 = rand() % 10;
 int operation = rand() % 4;

    printf("\tMATH TUTOR\n");
    if(operation == 1){
        printf("What is %d + %d ?", num1, operation, num2);
        scanf_s("%d",ans1);
        ans = num1 + num2;
        if(ans != ans1){
            printf("Incorrect! Try Again!");
            do{
                scanf_s("%d", &ans1);
            }while( ans != ans);
        }else{
            printf("Correct!");
        }
        }else if(operation == 2){
            printf("What is %d - %d ?", num1, operation, num2);
            scanf_s("%d",&ans1);
            ans = num1 - num2;
            if(ans != ans1){
                printf("Incorrect! Try Again!");
                do{
                    scanf_s("%d", &ans1);
                }while( ans != ans);
            }else{
                printf("Correct!");
                }
        }else if(operation == 3 ){
            printf("What is %d * %d ?", num1, operation, num2);
            scanf_s("%d",&ans1);
            ans = num1 * num2;
            if(ans != ans1){
                printf("Incorrect! Try Again!");
                do{
                    scanf_s("%d", &ans1);
                }while( ans != ans);
            }else{
                printf("Correct!");
            }
            }else if(operation == 4){
                printf("What is %d / %d ?", num1, operation, num2);
                scanf_s("%d",&ans1);
                ans = num1 / num2;
                if(ans != ans1){
                    printf("Incorrect! Try Again!");
                    do{
                        scanf_s("%d", &ans1);
                    }while( ans != ans);
                }else{
                    printf("Correct!");
                }
            }

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your code that will probably make it operate differently to how you expect.

You test for operation values of 1 through 4. operation is assigned it's value from rand() % 4. This means that operation will only ever have values of 0 through 3.

Your do while loops all have the same flaw. They test for ans != ans whereas you should be testing for ans != ans1.

Fix these problems and you will get a bit further.

**EDIT to give you a better hint**

```
if(operation == 1){
    printf("What is %d + %d ?", num1, num2);
    scanf_s("%d",ans1);
    ans = num1 + num2;
    if(ans != ans1){
        do{
            printf("Incorrect! Try Again!");
            scanf_s("%d", &ans1);
        }while( ans != ans1);
    }
    printf("Correct!");
}
```

**Edit to show use of srand**

```
int ans;
int ans1;
srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));  //I've included your (unsigned int) cast.
int num1 = rand() % 10 + 2;
int num2 = rand() % 10;
int operation = rand() % 4;
```

Comment: I changed it, but the random generator is not working properly. Is this how to put a range on the random generator?                    int operation = rand() % 4 + 1

Comment: Yes, that will work. There are other problems in your code though. Look at your printf's. Your code is printf("What is %d + %d ?", num1, operation, num2);  You have %d +(operator) %d. But you specify three arguments ... num1, operator, num2.  You should remove operator from this list.

Comment: thank you..I have a problem though whenever I run the program it keeps showing 2*8, and when I type the correct answer, it keeps showing Incorrect Try again

Comment: You should seed the random number generator before using it. Try something like srand(time(NULL));  Also, either try stepping through your code to see what is going wrong with a debugger. If this is not possible, try adding some logging to your program. For instance, change the printf("Incorrect! Try Again!") to printf("Incorrect! Try Again! Expected answer %d but you typed %d\n", ans, ans1);  This will help you track it down.

Comment: Hi this is what I did... int ans;
 int num1 = rand() % 10  + 1;
 int num2 = rand() % 10 + 1;
 int operation = rand() % 4 + 1;
 double ans1;
 srand(time(NULL));, and it still showing the same problem

Comment: it is accepting the correct answer now, but the problem is that it keeps showing 2*8.

Comment: Did you seed the random number generator at the start of your program? Before your first call to rand() be sure to use srand(time(NULL)). Otherwise rand() will return the same sequence of "random" numbers each time you run your program. You will probably need to #include <time.h>.

Comment: I included <time.h>. I placed 'srand(time(NULL)' before'rand()', but after int ans1; Is it right? I tried to put it before int ans, but the problem was that it gave me **C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'**, but I am not sure if  about the compiler. Another problem was that it gave me **warning C4244: 'function' : conversion from 'time_t' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of data**, so I put unsigned int and became srand((unsigned int)time(NULL))', now it is giving me **error C2065: 'num2' : undeclared identifier**, and **error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'**

Comment: I've edited my answer to show you what the code should look like. The compilation errors you describe would seem to indicate that you have either left out a closing bracket or the semi-colon.

Comment: I checked it, but there are no closing bracket or a semi colon missing. Is it working in your IDE?

Comment: I have figured it out. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Adding to John Sheridan's:  `getch()` is a non-standard extension to C that was added by many MS-DOS compilers.  It was usually defined in `<conio.h>`.  I don't know if VS2010 supports that by default.